# What to do if there is missing data in my categorical variable?

Tags: chi-squared-test, missing-data, yates-correction

I am hoping to conduct a chi-squared analysis between smoking status vs disease status. However, there are some missing data for my smoking status. Should I ignore those N/A when performing a chi-square analysis and if so, am I doing it correctly (pls see the code below)?

```r
chisq.test(na.omit(mydata$smoking), mydata$disease, 
    correct = TRUE)
```

Comment: It is important to understand what mechanism caused the smoking status to be missing.  Without taking this into account, your results may be biased.  Removing missing observations is not always correct.  Try multiple imputation using the ${\tt mice}$ package in ${\tt R}$.

Comment: Can you pls show me (e.g. R code) how to run chi-squared tests on the imputed data?

Comment: I will try to work on this now

Comment: In addition, code the missing values to a special code, and examine the crosstab. You want to know **where** the values are missing.

Answer (score 3):

This solution was taken from PowerPoint slides at https://nerler.github.io/EP16_Multiple_Imputation/slide/08_analysis_and_pooling.pdf  Pooling the chi-squared tests cannot be done using the ${\tt mice}$ package, but ${\tt miceadds}$ can handle this!

```r
    #Simulate Binary data for smoking and disease status \
    n = 50 \
    ind = c(4, 6, 22, 41, 50) \
    smoking = sample(c(0, 1), n, replace=TRUE, 
               prob = c(.2, .8)) \
    smoking[ind]=NA \
    disease = sample(c(0, 1), n, replace=TRUE, prob = c(.2,.8)) \
    X = cbind(s=smoking, d=disease) 
    
    library(mice) \
    library(miceadds) 
      #Must use this package if you want to pool chi-square tests 
    
    imp.data = mice(X, m=10, method="pmm") 
      #method chooses how to impute missing values \
    chisq.stats = with(imp.data, chisq.test(s,d,correct=TRUE)) 
     #Apply chi-square stat to each dataset\
    stat <- sapply(chisq.stats\\\$analyses, "[[", 'statistic') \
    dfs <- chisq.stats\\\$analyses[[1]]\\\$parameter \
    miceadds::micombine.chisquare(dk = stat, df = dfs)
```

Your code will not run since the two vectors will have different dimensions.  You'd also have to remove those observations of diseases that have missing smoking observations.  Fortunately, you don't have to add the `na.omit` function since `chisq.test` removes all records with a missing observation by default.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I try the code and I can run it even without removing the missing observation! However, I suspect I did not do it correctly because of the final output (pls see it below). Does this seem correct to you?                                              Combination of Chi-Square Statistics for Multiply Imputed Data
Using 10 Imputed Data Sets
F(2, 3.87715124659099e+31)=1.292     p=0.27476

Comment: Looks fine to me: the large denominator degrees of freedom is normal.  Make sure that if you are using character variables to specifically define them ${\tt as.factor}$ in R.  You can also fine-tune $m$, the number of imputations, as well as 'method' to determine how the results change.  Finally, all columns of the data matrix supplied to the ${\tt mice}$ function are used to impute the missing values.  You can fine-tune, if necessary, by reading the help page.  Out of curiosity, what was the p-value when you removed all missing observations?

Comment: Can I ask why you choose "pmm" method? Can that be applied to categorical variables (since pmm stands for predictive mean matching)?

Comment: and somehow I got the same p-value (0.2748) even without using imputation (I use "na.omit").. do you know why?

Comment: Ok very good, the p-value should be very similar to the imputed value, given the amount of missingness is small and the imputation model is not very strong.  I used the "pmm" method since it works for any type of data (see ?mice help page).  This is not to say that I would always use it for categorical data: logreg might perform better.

Comment: It occurs to me that MICE is for multivariate analysis but my chi-square analysis is only univariate (e.g. smoking status only). Can you pls explain why the miceadds function can be used for my example??

Comment: Anything that works for multivariate, works for univariate

Comment: Thanks for this!! I want to follow up with 1 more question: you previously mentioned we need to use miceadd for chi-square analysis. How about a t-test (both paired or unpaired)? Which type of MICE code should I use?

Comment: Can you pls explain these 3 steps from your above code???                                                                        stat <- sapply(chisq.stats$analyses, "[[", 'statistic')
dfs <- chisq.stats$analyses[[1]]$parameter
miceadds::micombine.chisquare(dk = stat, df = dfs)

Answer (score 0):

BTW, take a look at a crosstab which shows the missing values.  Recode them if you have to.  You want to see *where* things are missing.